# How to filter attributes in the Google Cloud Platform (GCP) Logs Explorer query using RegEx

Tags: google-cloud-platform, logging

Writing the query in the GCP Logs Explorer with a regular expression (RegEx) as the filter:

I need to filter the query_name for any string that has the word ¨stat" in it.

Tried it with the SQL way, and with wildcards:

```js
logName="projects/my_project/logs/my_env-production"
labels.query_name RLIKE "stat"
```

```js
logName="projects/my_project/logs/my_env-production"
labels.query_name LIKE "%stat%"
```

```js
logName="projects/my_project/logs/my_env-production"
labels.query_name="%stat%"
```

And RegEx, just to test the "." for any letter:

```js
logName="projects/my_project/logs/my_env-production"
labels.query_name LIKE ".stat."
```

The output is `No data found` on the left pane, and the output list is empty.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the same trick that is also used in Logs-Based Metrics or even in Grafana if you want to filter for RegEx.

```js
logName="projects/my_project/logs/my_env-production"
labels.query_name=~".stat."
```

Or take:

```js
labels.query_name!~".stat."
```

to avoid the RegEx.

(if you want it without RegEx, it is "=" and "!=", which is another pattern, that is why you might not find the RegEx on your own).